# Presburger Arithmetic Decision Procedures

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic

What are good textbook references for Presburger Arithmetic decision procedures?

Comment: http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=Presburger+arithmetic+algorithm

Comment: To be fair, it may be useful for an informed answer that explains the state of the art and the various tradeoffs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

John Harrison's handbook on automated theorem proving contains a fairly detailed description of Cooper's algorithm, including the steps necessary for an implementation in ML.

Harrison, J. (2009). *Handbook of practical logic and automated reasoning.* Cambridge University Press.